# How can I solve authentication error in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making discord bot using discord.py. But when I turned on the bot, it gets error discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 4004 (private use), reason = Authentication failed. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I already tried to generate new tokens, or make new bots. And the code which I'm using now was run successfully before. When I run this code in other computers(Which isn't have same ip), and it works properly. How can I solve this problem?

```
import asyncio
import discord

app = discord.Client()

def get_token(): # Get tokens from key.key
    global token # This part works properly
    f = open("Key.key", "r")
    token = str(f.readline())

@app.event
async def on_ready(): #Login Part
    print("Logining to : ")
    print(app.user.name)
    print(app.user.id)
    print("==========")
    game = discord.Game("Bot is working properly!")
    await app.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)



@app.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return None
    if message.content == "!hello":
        await message.channel.send("hello?")

get_token()
app.run(token)
```

This is my source code, and below one is traceback

```
  File "d:\Code\Project\discord_bot\Koi_Bot_Discord\Main.py", line 30, in <module>
    app.run(token)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 598, in run
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 579, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 543, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 457, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 421, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 476, in poll_event
    raise ConnectionClosed(exc, shard_id=self.shard_id) from exc
discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 4004 (private use), reason = Authentication failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update discord module using "python -m pip install -U discord.py" is a solution

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [environment variables](https://www.askpython.com/python/environment-variables-in-python) but if you insist on reading from a file, try:

```
def get_token(): # Get tokens from key.key
    with open("Key.key", "r") as f:
        return f.readline().strip()
...

app.run(get_token())
```

It is likely that you are getting a newline character from your `readline`, so `strip` will remove that, but having the function return your token is better practice.

Comment: My pleasure, if my answer has solved your problem please mark it as the solution, Thanks!